# Inheriting a web server control in a simple fashion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

I'm having a Repeater used as a sort of Paging TagCloud. To do so, I've added simple properties to the Page's ViewState such as a Page, RowCount, etc...

I feel like it doesn't belong there but I had bad experiences with server controls, debugging, dll and deployment.

Could I just inherit the Repeater class, add a few ControlState/ViewState properties and be able to use it exactly as a Repeater dragged straight from the ToolBox?

Here, having the following simple class:

```
    public class TagCloud : Repeater
{
    public int selectedIndex;

    public TagCloud()
    {
        selectedIndex = -1;
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return selectedIndex; }
        set { selectedIndex = value; }
    }
}
```

Without creating a new WebControlLibrary project, could this cs file stands in the App_Code folder and work like expected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is no problem doing this. As long as you use the control's property syntax:

public int RowCount
{

```
  get { return (int) (ViewState["RowCount"] ?? 0); }
  set { ViewState["RowCount"] = value; }
```

}

Also, to make your properties look the same as the default ones you can add Description or DefaultValue attributes.

Comment: I know how to declare properties that use the ViewState, if I am missing attributes, it is probably at the class level since there is no "TagCloud" in my ToolBox.

Comment: To have your custom control in the toolbox you need to create it in a new dll project, and then add it the toolbox via the "choose items" property.

Comment: Ight, thanks +1, is there a way to be able to use it like this then:
<whatever:TagCloud ID="TagCloud1" runat="server"></TagCloud>
without having it in the ToolBox and using the default Repeater's designer.

Comment: unfortunately no, if you want to use custom controls and use them in a markup way, you need to compile them to an assembly and then use the register directive. More information on that directive can be found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx here. If you don't want to deal with assemblies, you can create a repeater wrapper via user control, but this sounds little cumbersome to me.

Answer (score 0):

This works, and is one suggested way of building server controls. Try it and see.

Comment: I have a class TagCloud inheriting from Repeater having a simple int property. I must be missing attributes since the control doesn't seem to be exposed in the ToolBox. I would need the minimum required to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting from the ASP Repeater is a completely valid approach, so long as the control you are building IS a repeater with additional properties.

If you feel the control you need is actually "something else" that happens to have a repeater as part of its control set, then you likely need to make a composite control which adds a repeater to its control collection, along with whatever other controls are needed.

For example, you might want to have a control that has a repeater, a label of search results, links to go to the top and the bottom of the repeater's contents, etc.  This composite control is not a repeater, but does use a repeater.